# Advises for handling a 200 GB CSV with geometry

Tags: django, postgresql, orm, pandas, bigdata

I have a 200 GB CSV file that represent locations (points) around the globe. Each entry (row) has 64 columns and it has redundant information. I made some calculations and the size is approx. 800 million rows. My first approach was to push all the data into Postgres + Postgis. The data is not very clean and there are some rows that do not hold the datatype feature thus, I made an ORM implementation to first, validate and fix the datatype inconsistencies and handle exceptions. 
The ORM I used was Django > 1.5 and it took approx. 3 hours to process less than 0.1% of the total dataset. 
I tried also to partition the dataset in different files so that little by little I can process them pushing into the database. I used common unix commands like "Sed, Cat, AWK and Head" to do this but it takes so much time!

My questions are the following:

- Using Django ORM sounds like a god approach?
- What about SQLAlchemy could it help in making the insertions faster?
- How can I split the dataset in shorter time?
- I recently saw Pandas (Python library for data analysts) can it help with this task, maybe making the queries easier once the data is stored in the database.
- Which other tools would you recommend to work with this massive amount of data?

Thank you for your help and reading the long post.

Comment: 1) remove redundant columns. 2) use `split` to split the file into reasonable sized chunks (~ 1GB) 3)create a script to import the chunks one by one, separately. This will allow you to detect and correct errors in the data and/or interrupt the import process. 4) You may want to remove or disable constraints or indexes while importing.

Comment: 1) Import to a temporary table without any type checks. 2) Clean the table. 3) Move clean data to the main table.

Comment: Additional - check Postgres configuration. You can significantly reduce processing time by giving Postgres more resources.

Comment: If `cat file > /dev/null` takes too much time, then your case is hopeless on your current hardware.

Comment: Hi! thanks to everyone. I've been doing tests. I tried to cat everything in the dev/null and took more than 2 hours. Any other intent of parsing the dataset is going to take too much time. What I'm going to do is to use the split command, or make my own if it's too slow. But the question still is? Do you think that using the ORM methodology is a good approach? I will try to explore no-sql maybe it's faster.

Comment: I personally like PyTables for large data (http://www.pytables.org/moin).